# None of the constructors are called on passing Anonymous Object as argument

Tags: c++, c++11

```
#include <iostream>

struct Box
{
    Box()            { std::cout << "constructor called" << std::endl; }
    Box(const Box&)  { std::cout << "Copy constructor called" << std::endl; }
    Box(Box&&)       { std::cout << "Move constructor called" << std::endl; }
    void run() const { std::cout << "Run" << std::endl;}
};

int main()
{
    Box a(Box());
    a.run();
}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b196213b9867585e))

In the above code I was expecting either `Copy Constuctor` or `Move Constructor` to be called on passing anonymous object `Box()` as argument. But none of them were called. Reason probably might be `copy elision`. But even constructor is not called for anonymous object `A()`. Actually, the above code does not compile and on calling `run()` function compiler gave following error.

```
a.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
a.cpp:28:7: error: request for member ‘run’ in ‘a’, which is of non-class type ‘Box(Box (*)())’
     a.run();
```

So when we type `Box a(Box())` what is happening? What is being created?

Comment: You've been bitten by MVP. It thinks `Box a(Box());` is a declaration of a function named `a` returning a `Box`.

Comment: @YSC I'm not sure if I agree with your formatting -- I preferred the previous version.

Comment: @pingul shorter codes tend to attract more attention on SO, and my edit does not (I hope) alter the original intent of OP. But its definitely their call to rollback it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1424510/most-vexing-parse-why-doesnt-a-a-work)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is a case of the [Most Vexing Parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). When something could be parsed as a function declaration, it is.

```
Box a(Box())
```

is the declaration of a function named `a` taking a function of type `Box (*)()` as argument and returning a `Box`.

A solution is to use the (new in C++11) [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for constructing your objects:

```
Box a{Box{}}
```

([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9e04969dbd03b655))

---

The MVP is discussed in its simplest form in this stackoverflow question [Most vexing parse: why doesn't A a(()); work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1424510/5470596)

> If you do have an expression within then it is valid.  For example:
>
> ```
> ((0));//compiles
> ```
>
> To learn more about how languages are defined, and how compilers work, you should learn about [Formal language theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_language_theory) or more specifically [Context Free Grammars (CFG)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) and related material like finite state machines.  If you are interested in that though the wikipedia pages won't be enough, you'll have to get a book.

Comment: Should `Box a{Box{}}` not call the copy constructor?